# Array sort behaves incorrectly in a mobile browser angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have code simular to this:

```
const words = ['apple', 'banana', 'zoom']

words.sort((first, second) => {
  const a = first;
  const b = second;

  return a == b ? 0 : a < b || a == null ? -1 : 1;
```

It works correctly in desktop chrome, but in mobile chrome it sort vice versa.

Comment: This sort looks broken. Why would there be null in the array? That's a bit of an antipattern to begin with. Secondly, use parentheses when using the `||` operator to enforce precedence correctly. Thirdly, never use `==`. Use `===`. Avoid nested ternaries. See [javascript sorting array of mixed strings and null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328562/javascript-sorting-array-of-mixed-strings-and-null-values)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the view port or even Angular. Your sort function is buggy. Here is how to use sort in JS. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Problem was in ==. After i changed == to === sorting start work fine. @ggorlen thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using this way

For ASC

```
 const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();
console.log(fruits)
```

For DESC

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();
fruits.reverse();
console.log(fruits)
```